# Nginx image filter to fix a height and set a max width to crop only when required

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup an image carousel on my site - I need to handle most image sizes (generally 16:9, 4:3 and portrait).

to do this, we want to fix the image height to 90 pixels, and if it happens to be wider than 120, I'd prefer to crop the extra bits.  Although if its less than 120, I don't mind.

To do that, I expected this configuration to work.

```
location /myimage/x90/ {
    proxy_pass                      http://imagestore/;
    image_filter                    resize - 90;
    image_filter                    crop   120 -;
    image_filter_buffer             5M;
    image_filter_jpeg_quality       100;
    error_page                      415   = /empty;
    proxy_set_header                Host    $origin_host;
}
```

I expected resize to happen (which makes it 90 tall and maintains aspect ratio).  Then a crop to happen and keep that height.

However, It seems that the crop prevents resize from happening and all I get is a 120 wide image that is really tall.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html#image_filter) the image filter operations happens in the order: **crop**, **rotate**, **resize**.
I'm not aware of any way around this. You could *perhaps* resize, then redirect and crop?

**Update 2015/08/11:** The documentation appears to have changed, and the new operation order seems to be: **resize, rotate, crop**.

Comment: Ah, that would explain the behaviour. I was debating if it could be done via 2 rules that are "chained" one after each other.  Any idea how to do this? I am slightly worried it might lose image quality doing 2 separate operations, but I'll need to test it's acceptable.

Comment: @BruceLowe I did a bit of reading, but couldn't figure out any way, sorry. I haven't used Nginx image filtering myself.

Comment: @myanimal Has the order changed since you posted your answer? "When used along with the rotate parameter, the rotation happens before reduction."

Comment: @myanimal I'm confused. Did you see the bit of text I quoted above? it's in the `crop` option section

Comment: @Ursus ah, right. Had a quick read and misinterpreted it. So it looks like the order has changed to *resize, rotate, crop*. If that's how you also interpret the docs, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @myanimal yep, i'd go with that.